# What is the best way to secure the config file

Tags: boto

I know the question is very broad / vague. But what would be the best way to secure the .boto config file?

If I encrypt the file, how will boto know how to decrypt it again? Or does boto provide some other way for securing the config file?

Any suggestions / links would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boto on EC2 instances, use IAM Roles to get temporary credentials onto your instances.  These temporary credentials are rotated frequently and can be scoped to provide only the access necessary for your programs to do their jobs.

If IAM Roles don't work for you, you can also use `keyring` to securely store credentials in a boto config file.  You can find some simple instructions [here](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html).  You will need to install `keyring` on your computer in order to allow boto to take advantage of it.